# Xpath - How to get multiple values from Checkbox list as parameters

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt

I have a custom list that i'm filtering passing parameter from an asp.net control.
I do have some checkboxlist items, e,g below $priorChk.  The problem I have is if I select only one checkbox and filter its does work but not if I select multiple values.
I also tried printing out the values and I notice I just get only the first values.
How to pass multiple check box values as parameters to the /dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row?

When I test the below i also get error:

> Error while executing web part: System.BadImageFormatException: An
>   attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)  at (XmlQueryRuntime , XPathNavigator , Double , Double )  at
>   Root(XmlQueryRuntime )  at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object
>   defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList
>   argumentList, XmlWriter writer, Boolean closeWriter)  at
>   System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(IXPathNavigable contextDocument,
>   XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter
>   results)  at
>   System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(IXPathNavigable input,
>   XsltArgumentList arguments, XmlWriter results)  at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.ExecuteTransform(XslCompiledTransform
>   xslCompiledTransform, XsltArgumentList xmlArguments, Boolean
>   bDeferExecuteTransform)  at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean
>   bDeferExecuteTransform)

ASP.Net control:

```
 <ParameterBinding Name="priorChk" Location="Control(priorityChk)" DefaultValue=""/>
</br>
        <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" id="priorityChk" Width="179px">
        <asp:ListItem>Effective Immediately</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Action Required</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Key Changes</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:CheckBoxList>

<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[(number(ddwrt:FormatDateTime(ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@Created),1033,1),1033,'yyyyMMdd'))&gt;=number(ddwrt:FormatDateTime(ddwrt:FormatDate(string($sdate),1033,1),1033,'yyyyMMdd'))) and (number(ddwrt:FormatDateTime(ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@Created),1033,1),1033,'yyyyMMdd')) &lt;= number(ddwrt:FormatDateTime(ddwrt:FormatDate(string($edate),1033,1),1033,'yyyyMMdd'))) or (number(ddwrt:FormatDateTime(ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@Effective_x0020_Date),1033,1),1033,'yyyyMMdd'))) =
(number(ddwrt:FormatDateTime(ddwrt:FormatDate(string($effectDate),1033,1),1033,'yyyyMMdd'))) or ($title != '' and contains(@Title,string($title))) or ($priorChk != '' and  contains(@Priority,string($priorChk)))]"/>
```

Comment: Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

> Error while executing web part: System.BadImageFormatException: An
>   attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

this usually means you are trying to use a sharepoint dll (x64) x86 program? Your assemblies should all have the build type set to "Any CPU".

If this is not the case, sharepoint will return some really weird errors..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating multiple variables and then passing the variables into your xpath to filter on?

Comment: While your answer may answer the question it lacks extra content and is more suited as a comment, please refer to the [FAQ][1] for more information on how to post here. [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq